# Pass in an animation with ScrollTo?

Tags: uiscrollview, titanium, scrollto

When using the `scrollTo` function (a member of the `slideView` object), is it possible to pass in an animation as well so that I can control the speed of the scrolling and other pertinent variables?

If not, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about a `tableView.scrollToIndex` in which the [second](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableView.scrollToIndex-method.html) property is the animation.

Or are you talking about `scrollView.scrollTo` in which the properties are `x, y`? If it's this one then I don't believe there is a way to animate it using the `scrollTo` method.

Comment: The latter. Thanks for the info, anyhow.